# Определение сенсорных устройств Windows

Tags: winapi, windows, экран, ввод, мышь

Существует ли возможность через WinAPI узнать, является ли данное устройство сенсорным?
Подразумевается не возможность подключить сенсорный ввод, а именно наличие сенсорного экрана. 
Единственное, что пришло в голову, - это получить текущий курсор (у планшетов без подключенной мыши его нет), однако это слишком уж специфический способ. ))
Подскажите, пожалуйста, по каким запросам искать информацию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поясните, чего вы хотите добиться. Разного интерфейса для разных случаев?

Смотрите здесь:

- [Is it possible to let my c# wpf program know if the user has a touchscreen or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5673556/293099)
- [Why I can't detect touch screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923853/why-i-cant-detect-touch-screen)
- [How to specifically detect a touch screen display on Windows 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004911/how-to-specifically-detect-a-touch-screen-display-on-windows-8)

В общем случае, ключевые слова: detect touch screen.